# Can't run image, CMD ["npm", "start"] command error

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, docker-compose

> I just build app: docker build . -t ang:l
>
> after try run it: docker run -d -p 83:80 ang:l
>
> and get error:

**docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.**

without this CMD ["npm", "start"] command all works, but I need server and bd.

**Dockerfile:**

```js
# Stage 0, based on Node.js
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .

#RUN npm install
ARG configuration=production
RUN true && \
  npm run build:client-and-server-bundles -- --configuration=$configuration \
    && \
  npm prune --production && \
  true

# Stage 1, based on Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist /usr/src/app/

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

package.json command : "start": "node dist/server",

**Also I tried use docker-compose.yml:**

```js
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    container_name: ang
    image: ang:l
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

it's both variants don't work, help please, how to build it in docker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `nginx` docker image doesn't contain `npm`. You'll need to use `node:latest` which contains `npm`.

```
# Stage 1, based on Nginx
FROM node:latest
COPY --from=node /app/dist /usr/src/app/
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

You could potentially use `node:alpine` to run the application.